# Behavior of <- NULL on lists versus data.frames for removing data

Tags: r, dataframe

Many R users eventually figure out lots of ways to remove elements from their data. One way is to use `NULL`, particularly when you want to do something like drop a column from a `data.frame` or drop an element from a `list`.

Eventually, a user comes across a situation where they want to drop several columns from a `data.frame` at once, and they hit upon `<- list(NULL)` as the solution (since using `<- NULL` will result in an error).

A `data.frame` *is* a special type of `list`, so it wouldn't be too tough to imagine that the approaches for removing items from a `list` should be the same as removing columns from a `data.frame`. However, they produce different results, as can be seen in the example below.

```
## Make some small data--two data.frames and two lists
cars1 <- cars2 <- head(mtcars)[1:4]
cars3 <- cars4 <- as.list(cars2)

## Demonstration that the `list(NULL)` approach works
cars1[c("mpg", "cyl")] <- list(NULL)
cars1
#                   disp  hp
# Mazda RX4          160 110
# Mazda RX4 Wag      160 110
# Datsun 710         108  93
# Hornet 4 Drive     258 110
# Hornet Sportabout  360 175
# Valiant            225 105

## Demonstration that simply using `NULL` does not work
cars2[c("mpg", "cyl")] <- NULL
# Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, c("mpg", "cyl"), value = NULL) : 
#   replacement has 0 items, need 12
```

Switch to applying the same concept to a `list`, and compare the difference in behavior.

```
## Does not fully drop the items, but sets them to `NULL`
cars3[c("mpg", "cyl")] <- list(NULL)
# $mpg
# NULL
# 
# $cyl
# NULL
# 
# $disp
# [1] 160 160 108 258 360 225
# 
# $hp
# [1] 110 110  93 110 175 105

## *Does* drop the `list` items while this would
##   have produced an error with a `data.frame`
cars4[c("mpg", "cyl")] <- NULL
# $disp
# [1] 160 160 108 258 360 225
# 
# $hp
# [1] 110 110  93 110 175 105
```

---

The main questions I have are, if a `data.frame` is a `list`, why does it behave so differently in this scenario? Is there a foolproof way of knowing when an element will be dropped, when it will produce an error, and when it will simply be given a `NULL` value? Or do we depend on trial-and-error for this?

Comment: I'd note that this isn't specific to replacing multiple items in the data.frame/list with NULL: `cars1$mpg = NULL` vs `cars3$mpg = NULL` would demonstrate the issue just as well

Comment: I'd note that \`[<-.data.frame\` contains quite a bit of code, most of it dealing with various contingencies.  I'm too lazy to go find the piece you need, but surely the big answer to the question is that `data.frame`s get their own assignment method.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, thanks. I'll look into that code more closely too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER :** This is a relatively long answer, not very clear, and not very interesting, so feel free to skip it or to only read the (sort of) conclusion.

I've tried a bit of tracing on
`[<-.data.frame`, as suggested by Ari B. Friedman. Debugging starts on line 162 of the function, where there is a test to determine if `value` (the replacement value argument) is not a list.

## Case 1 : `value` is not a list

Then it is considered as a vector. Matrices and arrays are considered as one vector, like the help page says :

> Note that when the replacement value is an array (including a matrix)
>   it is *not* treated as a series of columns (as 'data.frame’ and
>   ‘as.data.frame’ do) but inserted as a single column.

If only one column of the data frame is selected in the LHS, then the only constraint is that the number of rows to be replaced must be equal to or a multiple of `length(value)`. If this is the case, `value` is recycled with `rep` if necessary and converted to a list. If `length(value)==0`, there is no recycling (as it is impossible), and `value` is just converted to a list.

If several columns of the data frame are selected in the LHS, then the constraint is a bit more complex : `length(value)` must be equal to or a multiple of the total number of elements to be replaced, ie the number of rows * the number of columns.

The exact test is the following :

```
(m < n * p && (m == 0L || (n * p)%%m))
```

Where `n` is the number of rows, `p` the number of columns, and `m` the length of `value`. If the condition is FALSE, then `value` is converted into an `n x p` matrix (thus recycled if necessary) and the matrix is splitted by columns into a list.

If `value` is NULL, then the condition is TRUE as `m==0`, and the function is stopped.
Note that the problem occurs for every `value` of length 0. For example,

```
cars1[,c("mpg")] <- numeric(0)
```

works, whereas :

```
cars1[,c("mpg","disp")] <- numeric(0)
```

fails in the same way as `cars1[,c("mpg","disp")] <- NULL`

## Case 2 : `value` is a list

If `value` is a list, then it is used to replace several columns at the same time. For example :

```
cars1[,c("mpg","disp")] <- list(1,2)
```

will replace `cars1$mpg` with a vector of 1s, and `cars1$disp` with a vector of 2s.

There is a sort of "double recycling" which happens here :

- first, the length of the `value` list must be less than or equal to the number of columns to be replaced. If it is less, then a classic recycling is done.
- second, for each element of the `value` list, its length must be equal to, greater than or a multiple of the number of rows to be replaced. If it is less, another recycling is done for each list element to match the number of rows. If it is more, a warning is displayed.

When the `value` in RHS is `list(NULL)`, nothing really happens, as recycling is impossible (`rep(NULL, 10)` is always `NULL`). But the code continues and in the end each column to be replaced is assigned `NULL`, ie is removed.

## Summary and (sort of) conclusion

`data.frame` and `list` behave differently because of the specific constraint on data frames, where each element must be of the same length. Removing several columns by assigning `NULL` fails not because of the `NULL` value by itself, but because `NULL` is of length 0. The error comes from a test which verifies if the length of the assigned value is a multiple of the number of elements to be replaced (number of rows * number of columns).

Handling the case of `value=NULL` for multiple columns doesn't seem difficult (by adding about four lines of simple code), but it requires to consider `NULL` as a special case. I'm not able to determine if it is not handled because it would break the logic of the function implementation, or because it would have side effects I don't know.

Comment: +1. It *is* interesting and somewhat along the lines of what I was assuming anyway (about recycling, in particular) but I hadn't really dug through any code to see what was going on.