# delete specified columns in a data frame (the names of target columns are stored in a list)

Tags: r, dataframe

In my data frame there are many specified columns, that I want to delete. I stored the target column names in a list, and I want to eliminate using of this, maybe that's the problem. 
even this didn't work:

```
for(i in 1:(length(columnnames))){ 
temp <- columnnames[i] 
DF$temp <- NULL 
}
```

because with this:

```
print(ncol(DF))
```

I got the original number of columns.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434778/behavior-of-null-on-lists-versus-data-frames-for-removing-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this

```
DF <- data.frame(A = c("a","a","a"), B = c("b","b","b"), C = c("c","c","c")) # Your data set
columnnames <- c("A", "B") # The columns you want to erase
DF <- DF[setdiff(names(DF), columnnames)]
```

Comment: +1. This is the way I would do this, but [there is a way to do it with `NULL` also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23093406/1270695).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for (i in columnnames) DF[[i]] <- NULL
```

Or in one go:

```
DF[columnnames] <- vector('list', length(columnnames))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using David's sample data, you can also use `list(NULL)` instead of just `NULL`:

```
## Your data.frame
DF <- data.frame(A = c("a","a","a"), 
                 B = c("b","b","b"), 
                 C = c("c","c","c"))

## The columns you want to remove
columnnames <- c("A", "B") 

## Removing them...
DF[columnnames] <- list(NULL)
DF
#   C
# 1 c
# 2 c
# 3 c
```

Comment: your solution is completely right, but I can accept just one answer, and I can't rate the answers yet at my current profile level. thanks!

Comment: @szandra, well, come back when you can :-)