# Deleting all variables with over 30% missing values

Tags: r, missing-data

I found this function to detect proportions of missing values for each column in any given dataframe:

```
propmiss <- function(dataframe) lapply(dataframe,function(x) data.frame(nmiss=sum(is.na(x)), n=length(x), propmiss=sum(is.na(x))/length(x)))
```

I assign it to a variable like this:

```
propmissdf <- propmiss(df)
```

Then I loop through the dataframe to NULL variables in my data like this:

```
for(i in (1:length(df))){  
  var = names(df)[i]
  if((propmissdf[[var]][[3]]) > 0.3) { #the 3 index represents the proportion inside propmissdf
  df[var] <- NULL   
   }
}
```

This gives me an error:

```
Error in if ((propmissdf[[var]][[3]]) > 0.3) { :argument is of length zero
```

But it works, somehow. It gets rid of several variables with missing value proportions greater than 0.3, but if I run the for loop again, it gets rid of more until 3 or 4 more times until it gets rid of all of them. Why is this happening? Please feel free to correct my problem, or to come up with a better way to remove variables with over 30% NAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
df <- df[colSums(is.na(df))/nrow(df) < .3]
```

- `colSums(is.na(df))` would calculate how many `NA` values there are in each column.
- Divide that output by the number of rows in the `data.frame` to get the proportion.
- Use `< .3` to create a logical comparison that can be used to subset the relevant columns.

---

Sample data and example:

```
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:4), 20, TRUE), nrow = 4))
df
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1 NA  4  2  3  4
# 2  3  4  2 NA  1
# 3  2 NA  2  2  2
# 4 NA  4  1  4 NA

colSums(is.na(df))/nrow(df)
#   X1   X2   X3   X4   X5 
# 0.50 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.25 

df[colSums(is.na(df))/nrow(df) < .3]
#   X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  4  2  3  4
# 2  4  2 NA  1
# 3 NA  2  2  2
# 4  4  1  4 NA
```

---

For reference, here's a quick timing comparison:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:4), 4000, TRUE), ncol = 1000))

akfun <- function() {
  i1 <-sapply(df, function(x) {
    pr <- prop.table(table(factor(is.na(x), levels=c(TRUE, FALSE))))
    pr[as.logical(names(pr))]< 0.3
  })
  df[i1]
}

amfun <- function() df[colSums(is.na(df))/nrow(df) < .3]

identical(amfun(), akfun())
# [1] TRUE

system.time(akfun())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.172   0.000   0.173 
system.time(amfun())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.000   0.000   0.001
```

Comment: how would you go about nulling the variables over 0.3 after this?

Comment: @jgozal, you just reassign the output: `df <- df[colSums(is.na(df))/nrow(df) < .3]`.

Answer (score 2):

We can loop over the columns with `sapply`, get the `count` of 'NA' values with `table`, use `prop.table to find the proportion and create a logical vector.

```
i1 <-sapply(df, function(x) {

      pr <- prop.table(table(factor(is.na(x), levels=c(TRUE, FALSE))))

      pr[as.logical(names(pr))]< 0.3

 })
```

This vector can be used for subsetting the columns.

```
df[i1]
```

If we need to remove the columns

```
df[!i1] <- list(NULL) #contributed by @Ananda Mahto
df
#   X2 X3 X4 X5
#1  4  2  3  4
#2  4  2 NA  1
#3 NA  2  2  2
#4  4  1  4 NA
```

NOTE: `df` taken from @Ananda Mahto's post

Comment: Try with `df <- cbind(df, df)`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434778/behavior-of-null-on-lists-versus-data-frames-for-removing-data).