# remove a column in R

Tags: r

I am still new to R and stuck at some trivial things

If i have data is like this:

```
 "","symbol","len","adjpv"
 "1","HLA-DRB4",5.196415406,0.02376069902
 "2","SCGB1A1",4.269985245,0.01861663475
```

I need new data to be set to data but without that first annoying column, **"", "1", "2"**

any help?

I tried **`newdata = data$symbol$len$adjpv`**

and **`newdata = data[ ,"symbol", "len", adjpv"]`**

**data$symbol** works but I need to grab all columns except the first one

Comment: Your approach works, if you combine the elements in a vector: `data[, c('symbol', 'len', 'adjpv')]`. But in general it might be the rowwnames-column, hence you could just define that using `row.names=1` when reading the data from CSV.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to use indexes when removing columns from a `data.frame` I prefer to actually specify their names for readability.

```
to.remove <- c('column1', 'column2') 
df <- df[, !colnames(df) %in% to.remove]
```

I find this approach quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
newData = data[,-1] //removes the first column
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you dataframe has the df as name.

```
colnames(df) <- c("firstcolumn","symbol", "len", "adjpv")
df$firstcolumn <- NULL
```

Comment: Works for dropping single columns but remember that you'll need `list(NULL)` to drop multiple columns. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19434778/1270695).

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 thank you for your comment. I though the question is for a simple column and as I wanted to start to learn R better answering question I tried to provide a possible solutin. If it is wrong I can remove the answer.

Comment: No need. Just pointing out that the approach is different if you're trying to remove more than one column at a time.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 yes of course. Just to learn what command you will use for multiples. Example `df <- list(NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove first col using negation (-):

```
newdata = data[ ,-1]
```

Comment: I still get the first column when I print :( tried all the above

Comment: Could you share your dataframe using `dput()`

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>%
    select(-1)
```

If you want to remove the first column, elsewhere you may pass the name of the variable you want to remove.